# Array of values within an ENUM?

Tags: c++

I have this code

```
enum type {NOTHING, SOMETHING, SOMETHINGELSE}
type *x;
```

At the moment I use `x[765] == SOMETHING` for example, How would I store other values for example

```
x[765] == SOMETHINGELSE;
x[765].position == 43.5;
x[765].somevar == 12;
```

I will apologize for my poor wording within my question im just starting out in C++, I know what I want i'm just not to sure on how to ask it.

Thanks.

Comment: `==` is the comparison operator. If you want the assignment operator then that is a single `=`.

Comment: If you're just starting out may I suggest one of the fine introductory books on the book list? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: I realize this, its just for demo purposes to show an example value :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if you're looking for a way to structure 'knowledge'; this is done with a struct or a class:

```
#include <vector>

struct Info {
   enum thingness { nothing, something };

   // 'member' variables
   thingness howMuch;
   int a_counter;
   float position;
};

int main(){
  Info object;
  object.howMuch=Info::something;
  object.a_counter=1;
  object.position=5.4;
```

You can group these kinds of objects into a container - typically an `std::vector`:

```
  // a container of InterestingValues
  std::vector<Info> container(300);

  container[299].howMuch=Info::nothing;
  container[299].a_counter=4;
  container[299].position = 3.3;

  // or assign rightaway:
  container[2] = object;
}
```

Comment: My compiler is returning: `error: object does not name a type`

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make yourself a more complex type:

```
struct type
{
    enum flag_type
    {
        NOTHING, SOMETHING, SOMETHINGELSE
    } flag;
    double position;
    int somevar;
};
```

and later have an array of this new `type.`

Answer (score 1):

Get yourself a good book to learn from. A list of good books is available here: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

In C++, you are asking how to declare an array of structures. Try this:

```
struct type {
    double position;
    int somevar;
};

type *x;
x[765].position = 43.5;
x[765].somevar = 12;
```

Answer (score 0):

An enum is a replaceable label basically for an int. You need to define a struct or a class.

```
struct type
{
   float position ;

};

type var;
var.position = 3.4;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your type enum would need to be a member of a class, along with the other fields. For example,

```
class MyType
{
public:
    type t;
    double position;
    int somevar;
};
```

With an array of `MyType` instances

```
MyType *x;
```

you would then be able to do what you ask expect you would need to do

```
x[765].t = SOMETHINGELSE;
```

to assign to the enum.